# How DID Microsoft do this? (an OO question about their .NET HttpServerUtility class)

Tags: .net, oop

HttpServerUtility contains a public function called UrlEncode.  It is not a shared function.  HttpServerUtility does not have any public constructors.

Doing this fails:

```
Dim encodeMe As String = "a string to be encoded!"
HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(encodeMe) 'Bombs out
```

This works, and is how Microsoft says to do it:

```
Dim instance As HttpServerUtility
Dim encodeMe As String = "a string to be encoded!"

instance.UrlEncode(encodeMe ) 'Works!
```

How did they accomplish this?  You can't instantiate an instance of it using a constructor, yet you can't access UrlEncode by just referencing HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode.

EDIT:  While I thoroughly enjoyed everyone getting into a big OO debate, I believe the problem is faulty MSDN documentation.  The line "Dim instance As HttpServerUtility" should read "Dim instance As HttpServerUtility = Context.Server"  The code which I included (which is from the MSDN documentation) does not actually work, and instead throws a null reference exception - just as you'd expect.  Thank you, Jason!

Comment: Bombs out with what? "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Comment: OOP 101: static/class methods != instance methods

Comment: Where did you find that second code of yours, where does Microsoft say that it works – and: did you actually test it? It does **not** work.

Comment: Although the documentation may be confusing,I'm not sure I would say it is wrong.The 'Visual Basic (Usage)' box is intended to give you an idea of how to declare a variable of the right type and how to call a method on it.It does not show how to get an instance.This information is replicated throughout all the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx, for instance.The code that should be used for testing is the one at the Sample Code boxes.They even have put a 'Copy Code' link on these boxes to avoid the need to select the code in the sample.

Comment: You're not going to link us to the faulty MSDN documentation?  That's kind of rude.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you sure this works?

```
Dim instance As HttpServerUtility
Dim encodeMe As String = "a string to be encoded!"
instance.UrlEncode(encodeMe) 'Works!
```

This will give you a `NullReferenceException` at runtime (and the compiler will give you a warning that `instance` is not being assigned to). Seriously, Microsoft didn't do anything here. The above code is disastrously wrong and will die at runtime.

And you can't do this

```
Dim encodeMe As String = "a string to be encoded!"
HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(encodeMe) 'Bombs out
```

because `UrlEncode` is not defined as a `Shared` method in `HttpServerUtility`.

You need a non-null instance of `HttpServerUtility`. The right way to use `HttpServerUtility` is like this:

```
Dim instance As HttpServerUtility = HttpContext.Server
Dim s As String = "Hello, World!"
Dim result As String = instance.UrlEncode(s)
```

Another option is to just use `HttpUtility` for which there is a `Shared` method `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`:

```
Dim s As String = "Hello, World!"
Dim result As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s)
```

Comment: @divo: Then it's wrong on MSDN (not the first time). It will crash at runtime.

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodeMe) will save much time and pain over this debate

Comment: @Jason: I looked in the MSDN’s description of the method and didn’t find anything that’s wrong – though the doc *is* bad.

Comment: @Jason I believe you're right - the doc is bad and should read HttpServerUtility instance = HttpContext.Server;

Comment: I just looked at the documentation. I think the confusion stems from the snippet labeled "Visual Basic (Usage)" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx). That is how all the documentation for VB.NET is written in MSDN. It's telling you that if you have a variable named `instance` of type `HttpServerUtility` and a variable named `s` of type string then you can invoke the method `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` via `instance.UrlEncode(s)`. For another example of exactly this type of documentation look at `StreamReader.Read` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, neither of the code examples you have given will work.

The first example will not work because UrlEncode is an instance method, therefore you cannot call it on the type, i.e. HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(encodeMe).

The second example will not work because the variable has not been assigned.

This has nothing to do with static constructors and the answers posted stating as such are misleading.

The HttpServerUtility type is designed to be initialised only internally by the System.Web assembly.  You cannot create your own instances of it. You can access an instance of it in a web application by using HttpContext.Server (which returns an instance of an HttpServerUtility).

Answer (score 2):

Use **HttpUtility.UrlEncode()** instead of **HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()**.  The version on HttpServerUtility is an instance method and not a shared/static method.  This has nothing to do with a static constructor (a static constructor would be called the first time a static method from the class is called)

Answer (score -4):

It has a static private constructor which allows it to be used.  Check out the following link:
[Static Constructors](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cupadhyay/StaticConstructors11092005061428AM/StaticConstructors.aspx)

If you want to see what they did download reflector and open it up.

EDIT: To flush out the answer to make people happy.  While the static constructor which is private allows the code to be written like it is in the question you do still need an instance for it to function correctly.

Comment: yes, but the point is that you do not have to actually create the instance to get it working, even though it is an instance member, not a shared one.

Comment: For the love of Donald Knuth no. This answer is wrong and should not have any upvotes. Just because there is a static constructor doesn't allow you to invoke methods on unassigned instances and not run into a runtime exception. The level of confusion in this thread is astounding.

Comment: What Jason said. You can invoke this method on a null reference. That normally dies with a NullReferenceException.

Comment: +1 to Jason... 
@Joshua - declaration of a variable absolutely does NOT create an instance of the type

Comment: @Joshua - your edit is also incorrect.  the static constructor does not allow code to be written as it does in the question.  both versions of the code in the question do not work